# How to get userID when writing Linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Here is my function in my kernel module which I insert using `insmod` command after `make` at later stages. I am working on  `goldfish (2.6.29)`

```
asmlinkage long our_sys_read(unsigned int fd, char  *buf, size_t count)
{
      printk("------->> our_sys_read getuid() ---------- %d\n", getuid());

      return original_call_read(fd,buf,count);
}
```

I want to trap system calls and find out which user made these system calls. But when I run 'make', it throws me following error.

```
/home/mohsin/LKM/trapcall.c:245: error: implicit declaration of function 'getuid'
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After spending two days, I finally figured out how to get uid of the process who made a system call. I will give all the suggestions I found on different links so that if my solution does not work, one of the others may work.

1) As told me Mats,

```
#include <include/linux/cred.h>

 static int getuid()
 {
     return current_uid();
 }
```

You call this function to get uid but it gave me negative numbers like `-943124788` etc.

2)

```
uid_t credd_uid ;
const struct cred *cred = current_cred();
credd_uid = current->cred->uid;
```

Same output like large negative numbers.

3)

```
uid_t struct_uid;
struct user_struct *u = current_user();

struct_uid = get_uid(u);
```

4) **Worked Solution**

It's given [here](http://www.faqs.org/docs/kernel/x931.html) actually.

i) Declare function prototype on the top like

```
asmlinkage int (*getuid_call)();
```

ii) Add following line to init_module() function

/* Get the system call for getuid */

```
  getuid_call = sys_call_table[__NR_getuid];
```

iii) Call the function in your trapped system call functions to get uid like

```
uid_t uid = getuid_call();
```

Comment: Looks difficult.. see how this code does it: drivers/android/binder.c:binder_ioctl_set_ctx_mgr()

Answer (score 6):

You could perhaps use this:

```
 #include <include/linux/cred.h>

 static int getuid()
 {
     return current_uid();
 }
```

cred stands for "credentials", and this macro returns the user-id of the currently active credentials. Bear in mind however that the "current user id" can mean multiple things in Linux.

[dan3 obviously didn't have to dig through quite as much code as I did to find this - or he started before me!]

Comment: I've used it before, but I can't say I remembered it off the top of my head :)

Comment: I have tested this code and it compiles perfectly good. But when I insert my module using insmod, it prints following UID which I guess is wrong.                                                           ------->> our_sys_read getuid() ---------- -1035134260
------->> our_sys_read getuid() ---------- -943124788

Comment: Hmm. Sounds a bit off to be fair. What is the user-id for your actual user?

Comment: Well..I am sure your answer would have not been different if I tell you I am working on Android kernel. I have checked in packages.xml file which contains all  userID list of installed apps. None of them have these two userID. They start from 10000 and then get incremented by one.

Comment: I do believe the user id is a combination of userid and a "namespace", but it sill doesn't explain the numbers you get - I think.

Comment: Actually I was trying your solution but it was giving me negative numbers as I mentioned in the above comment. Then I tried current->uid, it worked. But the problem is it always shows uid=112 or 116 or 120 while as per my research, Android userids are 0 (root) and then 1000+ for system apps and 10000+ for user apps.

Comment: That is strange. The current_uid() should work, since it is just a bunch of macros to get to the current task's credentials. As to what the UID is in your testing, I'm not sure what you should expect there.

Comment: `current_uid()` returns `kuid_t` which is a struct defined in `linux/uidgid.h` . There are some macros in that header to get and test the uid value.

Answer (score 5):

You need to call current_uid(), defined in linux/cred.h (starting with 2.6, used to be current->uid before). See the [kernel doc about credentials](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/credentials.txt)

current is a [macro](http://www.geeksww.com/tutorials/operating_systems/linux/tips_and_tricks/linux_kernel_data_structures_part_1__the_current_macro.php), BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the UID without using the `getuid` syscall hook:

```
#include "linux/cred.h"

static inline uid_t get_uid(void) {
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(3, 5, 0)
#include "linux/uidgid.h"
    // current_uid() returns struct in newer kernels
    return __kuid_val(current_uid());
#else
    return 0 == current_uid();
#endif
}
```

You should also look through `linux/uidgid.h` for useful macros that define ROOT uid/gid as well as inline comparison functions to avoid directly calling `__kuid_val()`.

For example, a common use would be to check if the user is root:

```
static inline bool is_root_uid(void) {
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(3, 5, 0)
#include "linux/uidgid.h"
    // current_uid() returns struct in newer kernels
    return uid_eq(current_uid(), GLOBAL_ROOT_UID);
#else
    return 0 == current_uid();
#endif
}
```